# Use JS/Jquery to change the styling of all the elements on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website that was styled using pixels...the problem is that it was developed on a screen with a high resolution and when you access it from a small resolution device it looks rather strange...

So my question is:

Is it possible to use javascript or any other form of front-end language to change to styling of all the elements (auto-detect them) on the page from pixel based to percentage based if resolution is smaller than x-given value (everything...from size to padding..etc)?

Ps. I know how to get the screen resolution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS media queries to solve te issue? Than you are not bound if the user has enabled JS or not. And does not slow down the loading time as much than JS.

Than you can depending on the resolution use specified CSS lines.

Example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  #container {
      width: 650px;
  }
}
```

More info: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: ...i have a small problem...i have many elements that have been re-styled on the page to fit (overwriting the default styling from the .css files) .. would the media query work without having to apply it to every modified element?

Comment: No, you will have to specify each elements new width.

Comment: ok..than the main question remains...there are just to many elements to modify manually...

Comment: i managed to solve the problem using your idea and a lot of manual work... thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

[CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

example:

```css
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
    body {
        background: #ccc;
    }
}
```

[Media_queries MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

[Media Queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/)

Comment: same question as above... can i apply the media query even to elements  that have an !important tag (to overwrite the styling from the .css files)?